# Determine the gcd of f(x) and f'(x)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, gcd-and-lcm

Let $n$ be a natural number, and set $f(x)=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Determine the gcd of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$. Then, determine for which natural numbers $n$ the polynomal $f(x)$ has multiple roots.

I've calculated $f'(x)=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$. I then tried to do polynomial long division by examining just a few of the highest degree terms and a few of the lowest degree terms, but that didn't seem to be getting me anywhere.

Comment: Hint: $f-f' = \frac{x^n}{n!}$. Any common divisor of $f$ and $f'$ must divide $f-f'$.

Answer (score 1):

Here $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ has no common roots:

If $f(u)=f'(u)=0$, then we must have $u^n/n!=0$; that is, $u=0$. Nonetheless, $f(u)=f'(u)=1\neq 0$, a contradiction.

Therefore, $\gcd(f(x),f'(x))=1$.

Note that if the gcd of $f$ and $f'$ has degree higher than $1$, then $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ must have at least one common root in $\mathbb{C}$.